# Does GCC atomic buitlins work with std=C99?

Tags: c, c++11, gcc

I am using this built-in atomic methods [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#g_t_005f_005fatomic-Builtins)
It is mentioned that:

> The following built-in functions approximately match the requirements
>   for the C++11 memory model.

However I have tried compiling these methods with `std=C99` and `std=C89`. The program compiles and I get the right results. Is there something I am missing here ?
Does `C99` and `C89` have a memory model as well ?

Comment: Are you asking about a C memory model or a C++ memory model?

Comment: C memory model. I wonder how these builtins do compile with C99 standard and C89, knowing that there is no memory model for C99

Comment: Which part of *"GNU C provides several language features not found in ISO standard C"* shown in the very first paragraph of the [parent page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions) of [your link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#g_t_005f_005fatomic-Builtins) baffles you?

Comment: no no. The problem is that in this page https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync they explain the behavior of these functions using the C++11 memory model. But I don't know what is the defined behavior in case I use this functio__atomic_load(a,12,__ATOMIC_CONSUME) of C99 for example. How is the __ATOMIC_CONSUME interepreted by the GCC.

Comment: They approximately match the requirements for the C++11 memory model - even with `-std=c99`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a compiler extension and therefore it is allowed to provide functionality outside of the what the standard allows but that page does not make it obvious that is the can be used in C.

Fortunately, gcc does have good [online documents](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) and if we check out for example the 4.9 series [document on C extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions) the [__atomic Builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#g_t_005f_005fatomic-Builtins) points to the same page.

So that would indicate that it is valid to use in C and it will stick the requirements as laid out in the documentation and so it will work in the C99 as it does in C++. Usually if there is a difference between how a feature/extension is implemented between C and C++ the documents will note this, for example [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) have significant differences.